# TypeError: create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'password'

Tags: django

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

# User Related Models
class cUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password, **other):
        if not email or username or password:
            raise ValueError('All fields must not be blank')
        
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, password=password,  **other)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **other):
        other.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other.setdefault('is_active', True)
        
        return self.create_user(email, password, **other)

class cUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    # superuser fields
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = cUserManager()
```

No idea what I'm doing wrong, I am clearly setting the password.. or am I? When I was searching for solutions it seems to that people don't make a password field in the user model, so maybe I'm overriding it and that's the reason for the error?

Comment: Try to use this `def create_user(self, email, username, password=None, **other):`

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin

# Create your models here.

# User Related Models
class cUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None, **other):
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=username, password=password, **other)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        print(password)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password, **other):
        other.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other.setdefault('is_active', True)
        
        return self.create_user(email, username, password, **other)

class cUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    # superuser fields
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = cUserManager()
```

Put the arguments in order and added the PermissionsMixin to cUser, and set the password=None, so that I can actually log in... dont forget the run migrations!